# Cancel previous, non-identical requests in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch data for a Leaflet map in an Angular app. For each zoom level I require different resolution data, which is why on `moveend` I make another call to the backend.

**map.component**

```js
    // Every time a movement is done on the map the calls are done again.
    this.map.on('moveend', () => {
      this.mapService.drawHeatMap();
    });
```

**map.service.ts**

```js
  public drawHeatMap(): void {
    this.fetchData().subscribe((data) => {
      // DO STUFF WITH DATA
    });
  }
```

```js
private fetchData(): Observable<Leaflet.HeatLatLngTuple[]> {
    return this.http.get<ResponseType>(URL).pipe(
      map(({ data }: ResponseType) => {
        return data.map((data: any) => {
          // PARSE DATA
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

During testing I saw that scroll in and out a lot makes the calls to my API get stack up, which is something I want to avoid.

When I tried canceling pending calls with `switchMap()` I don't get the desired result because the calls are not identical...

**Example request URLs from two different calls:**

`.../api/ZoomLevel=10&swLong=3&neLong=5&swLat=50&neLat=51`

`.../api/ZoomLevel=11&swLong=2&neLong=4&swLat=49&neLat=50`

Help to cancel the previous call **although it is not identical** would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening now - you are making calls on every event. In other words, making streams. Instead, you want one stream, in order to cancel previous call.

**map.component**

```
fromEvent(this.map, 'moveend').pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.mapService.drawHeatMap())
).subscribe();
```

**map.service.ts**

```
  public drawHeatMap(): void {
    return this.fetchData();
  }
```

p.s. obviously I haven't tested, so not sure whether `fromEvent(this.map, 'moveend')` is the right way to get that outer stream. Please provide the `this.map` API for possibly a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the HTTP request `observable` and the event one, are not chained to each other with one `pipe`, and one `subscribe`.

Besides, it's better in this type of event to use `RxJS` `debounceTime` operator to reduce the HTTP calls number.

You can try the following:

```js
fromEvent(this.map, 'moveend')
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300), // This will prevent calling the drawHeatMap within 300ms more than one time.
    switchMap(() => this.mapService.drawHeatMap())
  )
  .subscribe();
```

And within your `map.service`:

```js
public drawHeatMap(): Observable<any> {
  return this.fetchData().pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      // DO STUFF WITH DATA
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. In the end I was not able to wrap `this.map.on` in the `fromEvent()` operator, so I made a `mapEvent$` Subject which gets triggered everytime Leaflet registers a `moveend`. Then I subscribe to it and instead of using `switchMap()` I register active subscriptions in my service and cancel the previous call manually. That way I have more control and don't have to return cold observables from `updateMap()`

**map.component.ts**

```js
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initMapEvents();
  this.map.on('moveend', (val) => {
    this.mapService.mapEvent$.next(val);
  });
}

private initMapEvents(): void {
  this.mapService.updateMap();
  this.mapService.mapEvent$
    .pipe(debounceTime(ms), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.mapService.updateMap();
  });
}
```

**map.service.ts**

```js
public mapEvent$ = new Subject();
private activeSubscription!: Subscription;

public updateMap(): void {
  // cancel previous call
  if (this.activeSubscription) {
    this.activeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  this.activeSubscription = this.fetchData().subscribe((data) => {
    // DO STUFF WITH DATA
  });
}
```